# Uderstanding devextreme tags hierarchy and meaning

Tags: devextreme, devextreme-angular

looking at the grid, e.g.

```
<dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer" 
    [dataSource]="employees">
    
    <dxo-sorting mode="multiple"></dxo-sorting>
    
    <dxi-column dataField="Prefix" caption="Title" [width]="70"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="FirstName" sortOrder="asc"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="LastName" sortOrder="asc"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="City"></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

it has some `<dxo-xxxxx>` and some `<dxi-xxxxx>`, maybe others...

I havent found anything in the docs about how these objects are arranged. How does these tags are grouped? Does the prefix `dxo` stands for "option"? And the meaning of `dxi`? do exist other types of tags?
How can i explore them? where to watch? does anyone knows tell me something about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [configuration components](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular#configuration-components) documentation.